# How to add an HTML attribute to an item's inner template in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, extjs, extjs6

I'm trying to add a tag to an Ext JS component so that quality assurance teams can automate clicks on the application. The requirements state that each clickable element that will produce an event. So I guess my question is two-fold.

1. How do I get child components of an Ext JS component or container that subscribe to an onClick event or have a click handler attached to them?
2. Once I get the child component, how can I append an HTML attribute to the HTML that Ext JS generates?

A good example would be a combo box. I want all the data that is loaded and rendered to the DOM to have an automation attribute applied to it. So that when you open the combo box you get a whole bunch of HTML elements with automation tags or classes applied to them. Is there a way to override or mixin a function that would apply this class to inner items in a combo box?

Comment: Checkout xtemplates. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

Comment: Current version of the document: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.XTemplate.html